# Overlap() function not working in LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I am developing a tennis game in LIBGDX, in between i have to check collision between 2 players. When i try to detect it through overlap function with any movement of the ball by just placing it over the player it does detect the collision, but when i do it during the movement of the ball, it detects the collision of only one of the two player.....
For your understanding just Image a ball is moving from up to down, when ball reaches the 2nd player of my game, it does not detect any collision, Ball starts from 1st player by detecting its collision, but fails when reaches the 2nd player.....for checking the collision, in render function i added a simple code

```
if(this.getBounds().overlaps(game.white_player.getBounds()))
    {
        System.out.println("Over Lap.");

    }
```

i have surround both ball and player with a rectangle to check the collision....The code written above detects the collision when i manually place the over the player....but when i make ball revolve around, my code detects it only for 1st player,

Here is my complete render function code..

```
public void render(float delta) {

    game.red_player.update_rec();
    game.white_player.update_rec();

if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) 
        {
    touchDown(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 1,Input.Buttons.LEFT);

        }



if(up==true && down!=true && game.red_player.getBounds().overlaps(this.getBounds()))
    {

        shape_y+=1;
        going_up+=1;

        if(going_up > 720)
        {
            //going_up=200;
            //shape_y=200;
            System.out.println("yes");
            up = false;
            down = true;
        }

    }

    if(down == true)
        {
            shape_y-=1; 
            going_up-=1;
        }

    if(shape_y<200)
    {
        System.out.println("Lallaa");
        up=true;
        down=false;
        //going_up=201;
        //sshape_y=201;
    }


if(this.getBounds().overlaps(game.white_player.getBounds()) && shape_y==605)
    {
        System.out.println("Over Lap..");
        //up = true;
        //down = false; 
    }

    System.out.println(shape_x+" "+shape_y);

    game.batch.begin();
        game.background.actor.draw(game.batch);
        game.red_player.actor.draw(game.batch);
        game.white_player.actor.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    stage.draw();

    shapes.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shapes.setColor(1,1,0,0);
        shapes.circle(shape_x, shape_y,shape_width, shape_height);
        shapes.end();

        shapes.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapes.setColor(0,0,0,0);
        shapes.circle(shape_x, shape_y,shape_width+1, shape_height);
        shapes.end();

shapes.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapes.setColor(0,0,0,0);
shapes.rect(game.red_player.position.x,  
                game.red_player.position.y,game.red_player.width,
                game.red_player.height);

    shapes.end();

    shapes.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapes.setColor(0,0,0,0);
    shapes.rect(game.white_player.position.x, game.white_player.position.y,
                    game.white_player.width, game.white_player.height);
    shapes.end();

    shapes.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    shapes.setColor(0,0,0,0);
    shapes.rect(shape_x-10, shape_y-10, shape_width*2, shape_height/2);
    shapes.end();

}
```

Ignore all not defined functions...

Answer (score 1):

You could try drawing your player and ball bounds using ShapeRenderer class. Maybe you forget to update bounds coordinates to match the player or ball coordinates?
Example of how you could use ShapeRenderer:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.CYAN);
shapeRenderer.rect(player.getBounds().x, player.getBounds().y, player.getBounds().width,
    player.getBounds().getHeight());
shapeRenderer.end();
```

If everythings ok with the bounds, try rewriting you collisions code to something more simple:

```
if(ball.bounds.overlaps(anyPlayer.bounds)) {
    if(up) {
        up = false;
        down = true;
        System.out.println("Over Lap..");
    }
    else {
        up = true;
        down = false;
        System.out.println("Over Lap..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i sorted my problem last night, yes it was bownd co ordinates which i forgot to update..